# how to change the block size directly on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop2, hdfstore

My data is already on hdfs having block size 256mb. But have to change this block size to 128 MB. So how to change the block size directly on hdfs.

I tried

```
dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size = 128000000;
dfs.blocksize=128000000;
```

But my data is already on hdfs

Comment: set the dfs.block.size to 128 MB. Changing this setting will not affect the block size of any files currently in HDFS. It will only affect the block size of files placed into HDFS after this setting has taken effect.

Comment: I guess you will have to **copy** each and every file -- e.g. rename `/some/dir/` to `/some/olddir/`, run a `distcp` to re-generate `/some/dir/`, then delete `/some/olddir/` *(note that the checksums will probably be different because of the change in block size)*

Comment: yup i try this `hadoop distcp -Ddfs.block.size=128000000 /user/hive/warehouse/liveorc /user/hive/warehouse/liveorc1`  but i found some issue in data .

Comment: Ah, it depends on the way your **file format** is "splittable" -- with ORC for example you would have to use a Hive *INSERT-SELECT* query to make sure the stripes are correctly set within block boundaries...

Comment: yup i used ORC formate with Snappy compression